# jquery, control order of how code is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Via PHP, i'm generating some JavaScript code, witch looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(window).load(function() {
    maps.showUsers('Odenthal, Germany',1);
    maps.putCenter(51.1833,7.2);
  });
</script>
```

I have to be sure, that the first line is executed before the second line. This works fine in IE and FF, but not in Chrome. How can i control it?

Comment: Code usually executes sequentially. Is `showUsers()` asynchronous (does it return immediately and perform its task later)?

Comment: The first line of the function is always going to run before the second.

Comment: both methods are used with google.maps, the first one puts circles for users within a certain radius and is geocoding, sometimes there are two or three users and the function is called not only once, the last function should set the center of the map, after the usercircls are generated... so the setting the center works fine in ie and ff, but chrome sets a random center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with some delay. You can set the appropriate delay as per your need.

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    maps.showUsers('Odenthal, Germany',1);
    setTimeout(function(){
      maps.putCenter(51.1833,7.2);
    }, 400);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

try callbacks:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    maps.showUsers('Odenthal, Germany',1, function(){
        maps.putCenter(51.1833,7.2);
    });
});
```

you have to use that callback at the end of your function:

```
function showUsers(a, b, c, callback) {
    ...
    if(typeof callback == 'function')
        callback.call();
}
```

Comment: sorry, the code could also look like this, the explanation was a bit to short:

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
maps.showUsers('Leverkusen, Germany',1);
maps.showUsers('Solingen, Germany',1);
maps.showUsers('Wuppertal, Germany',2);
maps.showUsers('Obernzell, Germany',1);
maps.putCenter(51.1833,7.2);
</script>